# Using the wordpress loop in a random file

Tags: php, wordpress

For my frontpage I am using FrontPageSlideshow which generates a html/css/javascript element that displays articles and what not. Currently, it pull static entries from a file. I was able to make it dynamic for a Drupal site I worked on but now I'm stuck on a Wordpress one.

In the file I try to include a php file located within my Wordpress theme.

```
    <?php

$show = new WP_Query();

$show = query_posts(array(
     'category_name'      => 'News', 
     'posts_per_page'     => 4, 
     'orderby'       => 'date', 
     'order'         => 'DESC',
    ));

if (have_posts()) :
 while (have_posts()) : the_post() :
  $recentStories['article'.$articleNumber] = array(
   id      => $post->ID,
   title   => wp_title(),
   summary_name  => $post->post_name,
   dateMade=> the_date(),
   image   => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fp_image', true),
   summary => get_excerpt()
   );
  $articleNumber++;
 endwhile;
endif;

?>
```

However the problem is that it doesn't seem to be able to return any of my Wordpress posts. This file is included in another file along the lines of

```
$articleNumber = 1;
$recentStories = array();

include("wp-content/themes/Website/frontpage-post.php");

$slides = array();

// --- Start slide list ---
for ( $counter = 1; $counter <= 4; $counter++) {
 // slide elements
 array_push($slides, array(
  'slidelink'  => 'http://IPHERE/website/?p=' . $recentStories['article'.$counter]['id'],
  'title'      => $recentStories['article'.$counter]['title'],
  'category'   => 'News',
  'tagline'    => $recentStories['article'.$counter]['summary'],
  'text'       => $recentStories['article'.$counter]['summary_name'],
  'slideimage' => $recentStories['article'.$counter]['image'],
  ) 
 );
};
```

However, my loop keeps returning an empty array. I was wondering if it was possible to use the Wordpress loop outside of say the index.php page.

Comment: Assuming both files are in the active theme's folder, have you tried switching the include to.. `include("frontpage-post.php");`

Comment: Seconding t31os here - that path absolutely would not work. If you prepended it with a forward slash it would look relative to the root of the site, but if that is the exact path you're using it won't work. Have you tried enabling wp_debug to check for PHP errors? Also, try a `print_r()` on your `$recentStories` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For everything wordpress that is accessed outside wordpress system, you HAVE to include `wp-load.php`

```
include("wp-load.php");
include("wp-content/themes/Website/frontpage-post.php");
```